# Summing binary tree producing unexpected results

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

Trying to sum all nodes in a BST of Integers

The method is passed 0, but when it transitions from the left sub tree to right sub tree, the sum seems to decrease. Any help would be appreciated

The method is passed the root and a counter initialized to 0

```
public static int sumTree(TreeNode root,int sum) {
if (root != null) {
  System.out.println("current value: " + root.getValue());
  sum += (Integer) root.getValue();
  System.out.println(sum);
  sumTree(root.getLeft(),sum);
  sumTree(root.getRight(),sum);
}

return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sumTree(root.getLeft(),sum);
sumTree(root.getRight(),sum);
```

Just looking at these calls in isolation, they don't do anything. Their return values are being lost, and modifications to the recursive copies of `sum` don't affect the caller's `sum`; they're different variables.

```
public static int sumTree(TreeNode root) {
    if (root == null) {
        return 0;
    }

    System.out.println("current value: " + root.getValue());
    int sum = (Integer) root.getValue();
    System.out.println(sum);
    sum += sumTree(root.getLeft());
    sum += sumTree(root.getRight());

    return sum;
}
```

The fix is to add the return values of the two recursive calls to `sum`. There's no need to have `sum` as a parameter: the sum of a sub-tree is independent of the rest of the tree above it.